# Can wildcard characters be used in search in Chessbase for Android?

Tags: chessbase, android

When entering names as search criteria, do wildcards exist, like + for one character and * for many? I have made many attempts without any success.

Answer (score 1):

From your own experimentation and the lack of documentation from a Google search indicates that wildcards are not supported at this time.